# Source-built clang-3.7 on Linux not finding Block_copy

Tags: linux, cmake, clang, objective-c-blocks, autoconf

I built and installed llvm/clang-3.7 from source on my Ubuntu Linux system (I'm building from source because my development environment at work does not have apt-get available).  The gcc version is 4.8.2.  I followed the clang build instructions at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html, and everything worked fine (mkdir build; cd build; cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm; make; make install).  However, I'm now finding that a program to test Block_copy fails to compile.  The program is auto-generated by autoconf when I try to build gnustep-base.  The part that fails is:

```
int
main ()
{
    return _Block_copy ();
    ;
 return 0;
}
```

My compile command is:

```
clang -o conftest -m64 -march=opteron -mno-3dnow -ggdb -O2 -Wall  -I/home/build/GNUstep/Local/Library/Headers -I/home/build/GNUstep/Local/Library/Headers -I/home/build/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -fgnu-runtime -x objective-c -m64  -L/home/build/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/home/build/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/home/build/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries conftest.c -lrt -ldl  -lpthread -rdynamic -m64 -fgnu-runtime -L/home/build/GNUstep/Library/Libraries -L/home/build/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/home/build/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lm
```

Do I need to build clang with a special option to enable blocks, or should I be linking with another library?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to build clang with a special option to enable blocks

No. But you may need `-fblocks` option using the clang binary.

```
-fblocks
    Enable the "Blocks" language feature.
```

> should I be linking with another library?

AFAIK, Yes.

`_Block_copy` is a part of BlocksRuntime.

- [BlocksRuntime Block.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/28d10da69f52af1b01fbc12fd503621713641500/lib/BlocksRuntime/Block.h#L44)
- [BlocksRuntime runtime.c](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/28d10da69f52af1b01fbc12fd503621713641500/lib/BlocksRuntime/runtime.c#L453)

Have you compiled compiler-rt? It includes BlocksRuntime. [The document](http://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) explains how to build compiler-rt.

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out that clang no longer builds the BlocksRuntime on Linux by default, but it's possible to hack the cmake makefiles to request it.  I'm looking at that now.  Also, it turns out I don't even need block support from clang, because it's built into libobjc2, which I'm linking with.  :)